# How to create a jenkins pipeline to store the logs of a deployment (deployment evidences)

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have to log and store the deployment logs for a deployment. Could you please help me how to proceed with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store logs by [archiving them](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#jenkins-core). This ensures that each build has their own separate folder with the logs attached to them. One limitation is that the logs must be produced inside the workspace folder, or Jenkins will not be able to archive them.

In this kind of situation, you could simply have the pipeline create a new folder with the timestamp and move the logs there on success (or on failure as well depending on your use case).

Finally, you also have [plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/logging/) that can handle the logging for you if you define them properly.